# Wait for AsyncTask to be completed before 'PROCEEDING' in process

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my java code I have an event on button click, that it performs some actions, which are below

OnClick -> AsyncTask [OpenReader] -> if(not opened, return) -> else Proceed to process of onClick

What actually happens is a button is clicked, say there is a method need to be processed in that click, but before that process is initiated I have to execute/check openReader that is actually in between that process initiation and is an AsyncTask, so what happens is when I click openReader call initiated and before that is completed my process after that is started which shouldn't start until finish of AsyncTask, now if I wait for AsyncTask via while loop to finish it hangs the GUI, now what is the possible solution for this to handle?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    logMsg("....", R.color.GREEN);
    String phNum = phoneNumber.getText().toString();

    // Check if phone number is valid
    if (!checkNumber(phNum)) {
        required.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        validNum = false;
        return;
    }

    isReady = false;

    // Prepare device for use
    new openReader().execute();

            // Have to wait for openReader to finish here
            // and then proceed

    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
    case R.id.btnRead:
        flag = 1;
        // Process to be initiated here
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have onPostExecute method of Async Class, did you used that

Comment: Yes I have used that, but no in this situation, read my comment below

Comment: i think that is best way of doing things and you can create a method for this switch and call that method from onPsotExecute, and if you also want to block any further user interaction you can start progress dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**
just pass your clicked view's `id` along with the constructor of `openReader` class and then inside `onPostExecute` method you can use `switch` case.

**Example:**

```
int id = v.getId();
new openReader(id).execute();
```

and this is how your `openReader` class will look like,

```
private class openReader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
      private int selected_v_id;

public openReader(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        selected_v_id= i;
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


               switch (selected_v_id) {
               case R.id.btnRead:
                      flag = 1;
                    // Process to be initiated here
               break;
               default:
               break;
           }


    }


}
```

**Edit:**

if you want to clear the mess inside `onPostExecute` method,
you can do something like this,

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
        performAction(selected_v_id);
}



private void performAction(int x)
{
               switch (selected_v_id) {
               case R.id.btnRead:
                      flag = 1;
                    // Process to be initiated here
               break;
               default:
               break;
           }

}
```

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: well, that's a better decent solution, I am voting up, but will accept the answer as soon as I implement it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

See [AsyncTask.onPostExecute()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29). Place any code that needs to run after the AsyncTask completes inside this method.

Comment: yes I have that method and know how to use that, but in my situation when I click button it gets ID of that button and according to that performs action, if I use onPostExecute() method I shall have to place all my switch code there which I want to avoid, that's why I need a work around...

Comment: @Saqib: have a look at my answer which handles what you need.